# Правильное объявление коллекций

Tags: java

```
Set set = new HashSet(); 
Map map = new HashMap();
List list = new ArrayList();
```

Почему для этих реализаций пишут вот так, а не вот так:

```
HashSet set = new HashSet();
HashMap map = new HashMap();
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
```

Я понимаю что допустим `Set` это интерфейс, а `ArrayList` реализация/ Используют `List list = new ArrayList();` потому что методы

> List(a) + методы ArrayList = perfect?
>   Из-за этого пишут `List list = new ArrayList();`? Поясните пожалуйста

Comment: такой же вопрос у меня

Comment: Потому что один из базовых принципов ООП - это программирование на уровне интерфейсов, а не реализаций. Из него же вытекают сразу несколько принципов [SOLID](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала, так пишут как минимум потому, что нельзя сделать объект в виде интерфейса, то есть, вы не можете сделать так

```
List list = new List ();
Map map = new Map ();
```

Посмотрите на [этот](https://stackoverflow.com/q/147468/9719337) вопрос,где вы также сможете вот эту [статью](https://www.javaworld.com/article/2073649/why-extends-is-evil.html), которая, возможно, он вам вам более полно даст ответ.

В кратце, ваш пример

> HashSet set = new HashSet();
>
> HashMap map = new HashMap();
>
> ArrayList list = new ArrayList();

не будет считаться ошибкой, его можно улучшить, потому что в будущем, при работе с большим объемом кода, вам проще обращаться именно к интерфейсу, или так скажем, к более общему объекту/классу/сущности, нежели к ее конкретной реализации.

Например, у вас будет интерфейс `Programmer` и классы, которые реализуют его
`JavaProgrammer`, `JavaScriptProgrammer`, `PhpProgrammer` ... Вам ведь удобнее в List добавлять Программистов, а не создавать для каждого типа программистов свой лист, ведь так?
В итоге у вас просто будет

```
List<Programmer> программисты = Arrays.AsList(new JavaProgrammer(),new JavaScriptProgrammer(), new PhpProgrammer()  );
```

вместо отедльных списков для каждого типа программиста.

Comment: Спасибо! Вске понятно

Comment: ISP[8] 
Принцип разделения интерфейса (The Interface Segregation Principle)
«много интерфейсов, специально предназначенных для клиентов, лучше, чем один интерфейс общего назначения.»[9]  Прочитал в википедии. Как понять много интерфейсов, лучше чем один интерфейс? :D

Comment: А вы переходили по [ссылке](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BF_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%B0)? Это, значит, что не нужно делать 1 интерфейс на всю программу. Логика тоже должна разделяться между ними

Answer (score 2):

`List`- это интерфейс, все коллекции, которые его реализуют, реализуют все его методы. Поэтому удобно(и принято в ооп) использовать интерфейсы.  На пример в качестве аргумента в методе вы можете использовать интерфейс `List`

```
public void someMethod(List<String> list)  {
}
```

В этот метод вы можете передавать `ArrayList`, `LinkedList` и любую другую коллекцию, реализующую `List`.